# How to add folder to PYTHONPATH in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have a python library in a folder which is not recognised by Anaconda Jupyter Notebook, so if I `import <module name>` I get `No module named '<module name>'`.

How can I add the folder to the path? Spyder has the pythonpath manager in which I can just add a folder, but I cannot see how to do it in Jupyter Notebook.

Followup question: is there a way to add a folder to the python path, such that all Anaconda applications, Spyder, Jupyter, etc., recognise it? Or dies it have to be done for each application separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending the path via `sys.path.append(path)`.
Docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

EDIT:
Another option would be to install your package in [editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) mode so that it runs from the current location.

Comment: Hi @Brian Larsen . This works thanks! However it has to be redone for any new Notebook I create. I was wondering if there was a way that Jupyter notices those packages by default, without me having to enter that line every time.

Comment: @Britzel, I edited the answer to also suggest installing in editable mode.

Answer (score 1):

PYTHONPATH is an environment variable that you can set to add additional directories where python will look for modules and packages. The `how to` depends on your OS. In Windows just search for `environment variables`.

The only reason to set PYTHONPATH is to access directories with custom libraries that you do not want to install in the default location, i.e. the `site-packages` directory.

Comment: Hi @Peter ! So far I think I understood it. I guess I could try to copy the library into the site-packages folder. But I am still curious how to add another directory to the path in Anaconda Jupyter. As said, I know how to do it in Spyder, but that doesn't effect the Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: There is nothing like a `path in Anaconda Jupyter or Spyder`, there is only the `Python sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` and `site-packages` are a part of it. You can tweak and hack the `sys.path`, but this only works on a beginner level. The proper way to access your packages is to `conda install (Anaconda)` or `pip install` them and to let these package managers take care of all dependencies too. To install a local package in the Anaconda ecosystem you would use `conda develop path/to/your/directory`.