# Unable to import the package in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am unable to import the package in the conda env inside jupyter notebook. [image]

I can import the package via terminal but it's not loading in the notebook.

Can someone help me to debug this?

Update: Tried to add site-packages to path as well as per the suggestions by @Azhar[image]

Comment: Try appending `env\tgt\lib\site-packages` to `PYTHONPATH`. Refer [if I import <module name> I get No module named '<module name>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247753/how-to-add-folder-to-pythonpath-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: I added the path to env var but it's still not working.

Comment: Always use `%pip` or `%conda` inside a cell in a Jupyter notebook (as long as you aren't working in google colab). You'll get confusing results using an exclamation point. If you aren't familiar with the modern magic commands, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). So in your example, you'd run `%pip install lasio` in the notebook, restart the kernel, and then try the import statement again. Or use `%conda install lasio` if it will install via conda and you are primarily using that to handle your packages.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. Solution for me was:

1. In jupyter print `%pip install lasio`
2. Reset the kernel and start again

That's all. By the way, via conda it didn't work.
Good lick!

Comment: My comment below the OP from September of last year about the modern magic command `%pip install` has [a useful link](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for anyone more curious about this modern magic command. The magic `%pip install` insures the installation occurs in the environment that the kernel underlying the notebook is using. The exclamation point used in the image in the OP doesn't do that and so it can lead to issues.